# Check multiple condition using C# in aspnet

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-update

On the table MySQL I have memorized these values :

```
+---+-------+------+
| A | B     | C    |
+---+-------+------+
| 0 | 16,11 | 3,08 |
+---+-------+------+
1 row in set
```

I need check this condition using C# in aspnet :

```
if (A < 0.1 && B > 1 && (C >= 1 && C <= 4))
```

When all conditions are true I need set the column D as true.

The column A, B and C are setting as Decimal 10,2 value.

But the output it's false.

How can I resolve this ?

**Edit #01**

```
            A = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["A"]);  //a
            B = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["B"]);  //b
            C = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["C"]);  //c
```

**Edit #02**

[image]

Comment: Your condition "(A < 0.1 && B > 1 && (C >= 1 && C <= 4))" is fine and it should return true if the values are exact the same what you wrote in table. However, debug the value of A, B and C during run time, i suspect it would be different than what you wrote in table;

Comment: @Golia In your database Column B and Column C contains more than one value, it cannot be converted into double. Please see my answer

Comment: @NitikaChopra Thanks for reply, please see **Edit #02** in my first question, **Split** method report error

Comment: @Golia ... u should convert into string  Convert.ToString(dt2.Rows[0]["A"]).Split(',');
You can try this

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple `update` query:

```
update mytable
set d = 1
where a < 0.1 and b > 1 and c >= 1 and c <= 4
```

This will set `d` to `1` where the conditions are satisfied.

If you want to set to `0` or `1` depending whether the conditions are met or not:

```
update mytable
set d = (a < 0.1 and b > 1 and c >= 1 and c <= 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is true and should be work correctly.

Are you sure about A,B,C value?

Comment: Thanks for reply, please see **Edit #01** in my first question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you:-

```
Double[] Aarr= A.Split(',');
Double[] Barr= B.Split(',');
Double[] Carr = C.Split(',');

long ACount = Aarr.Where(x => x < 0.1).Count();
long BCount = Barr.Where(x => x > 1).Count();
long CCount = Carr.Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4).Count();

if((ACount == 1) && (BCount == 1) && (CCount == 1)
{
    //Your Code
}
```

Thanks!!!